# Remotely triggering a computer on a different network

Tags: python, remote-access

I have a script I wish to trigger with an input string from a completely remote source, with <2s latency. I was considering setting up a website to trigger it but that just seems like a bad option.

Ideally I'm looking for some package that can communicate with another python script via some existing server, but this might be too optimistic. Is there an elegant way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy to do with [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) assuming you can make an SSH connection to the machine. You should be able to achieve <2s latency quite comfortably - that's a pretty long time for executing a single command (assuming you're not expecting the script to execute and return something).

In your Python script you can use something like this:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd_to_execute)
```